# how to bring a task to foreground

Tags: android

The use case is: User opens Settings->Applications->Manage applications->choose some application->select "Uninstall"->A confirmation UI appears with "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons

then user press"Home" button and "Home" is displayed.

Here comes my question: how to programmatically bring the "Confirmation UI" to the foreground?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for creating a dialog?

Have a look [here for Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog), you'd need AlertDialog from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Gix answer looks good.
In general you can start any Activity to bring it to foreground.

```
if (!Preferences.running || view == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.context,                 YourActivity.class);
            if (message != null)
                intent = intent.putExtra("message", message);
            // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
            intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);// Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            try {
                Preferences.context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                Preferences.context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else 
            view.bringToFront();
```